# Using the K-Nearest Neighbors classifier and y is changed from an int to a float on the scikit-learn website. Why is this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I was going through some scikit-learn tutorials on their website and in one of the exercises they changed the sample type from an int to a float.  The code still works if it remains an int.  My guess is that it has something to do with type coercion but I was wondering if anyone could explain *why* this is being done.  Below is includes the code I am looking at and the link to the scikit-learn page with the relevant example.  The example is the file at the very bottom of that page.  Thanks!

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import datasets, svm

iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target

X = X[y != 0, :2]
y = y[y != 0]

n_sample = len(X)

np.random.seed(0)
order = np.random.permutation(n_sample)
X = X[order]
y = y[order].astype(np.float)
```

[Source](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/statistical_inference/supervised_learning.html)

Comment: Are you talking about this file: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/_downloads/plot_iris_exercise.py ??  Are you able to run it? Are you not getting any errors?

Comment: By the way, internally input targets (`y`) to almost all classifiers are converted to float before further processing. So it doesn't make any difference if you convert in yourself or not. And it has no special meaning. Just a way to keep things consistent. Because all svm implementations in scikit-learn extend the libsvm library.

Comment: Yes.  It works.  I was just wondering why it was done this way, I assume there is a reason behind it.